# unable to pass in params w/ SMS:// deeplink on iOS 11 when iOS Messages is not already open

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios11

I'm trying to invoke the following url on iOS 11.0 developer preview:

```
<html>
<body>
  <a href="sms:+24321&body=This%20is%20the%20body">Click Me!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When you click the link above, iOS successfully opens the native iOS Messages application. If the user previously had the iOS Messages app open in the background on their phone, then iOS properly passes in the query parameters contained in the link, e.g. `to:` (24321) and `body:` (This is the body), but if the user does NOT already have iOS Messages open, then iOS opens Messages, but does NOT open a message w/ `to` and `body` filled out.

This is not an issue on iOS 10, it seems to have been introduced in iOS 11.

Comment: iOS 11 is still in beta so this can change. Also if you find a but like this you should report it to Apple so they can fix it before the release.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I filed a bug w/ them. It feels like they wouldn't intentionally remove this functionality, but was wondering if anyone else encountered this.

Comment: This is still an issue in the public release of iOS 11. Does anyone know of any workarounds?

Comment: I am seeing this issue with deep linking to my own app. If the app is not yet open, the url scheme correctly opens the app, but it doesn't get the parameters. If the app is open, it opens the app and passes the parameters. This is with iOS11.0.1. I haven't tried iOS11.1 Beta.

Comment: I just tried this on iOS11.1 Beta, and find the same situation-- I am not getting parameters.

Comment: In my case, I just learned that this does *not* have to do with "not getting parameters". Rather it has to do with the ordering/timing of when a delegate gets set. My delegate gets set in `viewDidLoad` of my root view controller. In iOS 11 (but not in earlier versions of iOS), viewDidLoad of the root view controller gets called *after* `application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool` of the app delegate gets called.

Comment: issue still their in iOS11 official release, any idea how to fix it in web?

Comment: Any solution yet? We are also facing this issue.